# Stack Exchange Login not working

Tags: support

My external IP address recently changed and now I find that I cannot login to any SE site except SO.  I'm posting here because I cannot even login to Meta.SE.

When I visit any site on which I have an account I see the "Join this community" link and no Login link. For example:

[image]

If I click the SE dropdown at the top left, it gives me a "log out" option but I am not logged in.

[image]

If I try to register my current email and password (i.e. use the "Join this Community" link) it appears to succeed but I just get back to the same non-logged-in screen.

From SO, I see my logged-in status on Home Improvement:

[image]

As you can see it shows my current rep. However, if I click on the link I'm taken to a non-logged-in page with the "Join this community" link.  I've already tried clearing the browser cache and cookies for the site.

Suggestions?

Comment: My IP address changes frequently and I haven't faced that issue yet. Do you have cookies disabled? Or recently installed some browser plug-in? Ad-blocker, Request-Policy, no-scripts, someting like that?

Comment: Nothing like that, no changes other than external IP changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the `logout` link (see second image above) and logging back in.  This may be a bug so I'll leave the question open for a bit but will be deleting it unless someone wants to keep it.