# How can I abandon my in-progress Stack Exchange signup, in favour of my existing Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, login

Two days ago, I contributed [an answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/41214/33880) on chess.SE. Without thinking, rather than using the feature to associate the post with my Stack Overflow login, I completed the "post as a guest" form, filling in my name and the same email that I use for Stack Overflow.

Now, when I try to post on any Stack Exchange site - including ones like japanese.SE where I would normally be logged in with an [existing, long-standing account](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/627/karl-knechtel) - I'm confronted with the logged-out interface and a "Join this community" button. (This also applies to meta.SE, which is why I'm asking here.) I haven't logged out from anything, so I'm confused by this behaviour. How can I get back to how things were before (and, ideally, also associate the guest post with my existing Stack Exchange presence)?

Edit: Based on [Stack Exchange Login not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340526/stack-exchange-login-not-working), I tried logging out and in again from Stack Overflow, and refreshing tabs for the other SE sites - this had no observable effect for me, however.

Comment: What happens when you try logging in on those sites, as you don't tell us that.

Comment: There wasn't a button to log in, that's the thing.

Comment: "Join this community" is your login button; what happens when you "join" the community?

Comment: It gave me a form to complete a signup procedure. I didn't want to proceed with this, because the point is to use my existing account.

Comment: What type of account did you use to sign up on [so] (for example Google, GitHub)? Do you have any other accounts other than that account type?

Comment: My suggestions, based on some assumptions/guesses: You have not completed registration with the new account. I would suggest that you do so. Once you complete that registration, you should be able to log out of that account (don't do so prior to completing registration, or, at least not until you receive the email to complete registration; assumed, I'd error on the side of caution and not log out until complete), and be able to log in again to either that account or your main one. Once that is the case, use the "Contact Us" form to request a merge of the accounts.

Comment: It was only one post, so I am not too concerned if it can't be merged now that I've acted more rashly.

Comment: @Larnu since merging one other old account, I shouldn't have others besides this one. I log into it manually, not via an external OpenID service. I don't think those options existed 12 years ago.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm sure I've read something recentlyish that if you used a sign in method unique to a site (such as GitHub on [so]) you needed to now add another authentication method to sign up/into other sites now

Answer (score 5):

I resolved the problem as follows:

1. Log out *from chess.SE* - apparently, posting as a guest puts you in a state that is still considered "logged in", even though signup is incomplete.
2. Refresh a tab for another SE site; this offered me a login button.
3. Log in with the same credentials I use on Stack Overflow. Now I have my usual access to all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Do you still have access to the new account on [chess.se]?

Comment: Doesn't appear so.

Comment: Well, you can try asking for a merge through [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact), which may or may not be automatic. If it's not automatic, it will require someone on SO Staff, so won't happen until January, given that the company is, effectively, shut down until then.

Comment: You should have received an email from SO about completing registration. If you follow the directions in that email to fully register the new account, you may be able to regain access to the new account on [chess.se]. If so, then you'll just need to handle the accounts as you would for with any alternate account (including, optionally, asking for a merge). Personally, I just use separate browser profiles/people, as I find that an easy way to keep them separate (and it's one of the thing for which browser profiles/people were designed).

Comment: I managed to find such an email. I'll see about it after the holidays, if I still care.

Comment: It would be fairly "normal" practice for the links provided in such an email to be valid for only a limited period of time. I don't recall if Stack Overflow has a time limit on the validity of such links, or what that limit is, if it exists, but I've certainly seen other sites where that period of time is measured in minutes. Thus, choosing to delay completing registration *may* be equivalent to choosing not to complete registration at all. I'd expect that the account could still be merged without needing you to complete registration, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Mm. The link already appears not to work. It's been two days already, after all.